# Rails console - how to search on a model that has 2 words in its name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I have this table in my schema:

```
create_table "organisation_requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "profile_id"
    t.integer  "organisation_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I expect to be able to search my rails console as follows:

```
OrganisationRequest.new
OrganisationRequest.last
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
OrganisationRequest Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "organisation_requests".* FROM "organisation_requests"  ORDER BY "organisation_requests"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "organisation_requests" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "organisation_requests".* FROM "organisation_request...
                                               ^
: SELECT  "organisation_requests".* FROM "organisation_requests"  ORDER BY "organisation_requests"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "organisation_requests" does not exist
```

Is there something special I need to do to be able to search the console on models that have two words in the name?

Comment: Are you sure you ran `rake db:migrate`, I mean it is not pending?

Comment: yes - im sure its not pending

Comment: can you exit console and restart it again?

Comment: I have turned off the computer and started again. Im trying to reset the database now to see if that works

Comment: it works fine now that i reset the database